# Using History API to Store State

Tags: angular, angular-material

When navigating away from my component, I would like to store some state information in the browser history-state-object so I can restore it if I navigate back. I would like to avoid using a service to store this information as I don't want to restore these properties if I "freshly" navigate to my component - only if I use the browser-back-button (or `location.back()`).

I was thinking of doing something like this in the component that's being navigated away from:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  let state: any = this.location.getState();
  this.location.replaceState("", undefined, { ...state, selectedTabIdx: this.selIdx });
}
```

and the following in the same component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  let state = this.location.getState();

  if (state.selectedTabIdx !== undefined)
    this.selIdx = state.selectedTabIdx;
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? The above code doesn't work (it's more of a wishful thinking exercise) as the state I get in `ngOnInit` doesn't contain the property `selectedTabIdx`.

I'm thinking that the history-state-object would be the perfect place to store this information as it should only be for this step in history and maybe you could have the same component multiple times in your history and with different selections etc.

Comment: By navigating away from a component do you mean, going to a new website, or going to another component within your application?

Comment: Going to another component within my application (e.g. `[routerLink]`)

Comment: Have you considered localstorage/sessionstorage to store your state?

Comment: Yes - it would result in the same as storing it in a service-variable: It is too persistent and the context of the history is lost. Whenever I navigate to my component again (through a `routerLink`), the state would be restored and I don't want that. I only want to restore the state if I used `location.back()`

Comment: Also, if my component is in the history twice (because from my component I navigated through a routerLink to another component, then through more routerLinks to my original component and away again), I want them to be able to have different states (the first time I navigated to it, I changed the TabIdx to 3 and the second time to 2) - so if I go back I land on the TabIdx 2, and if I go back and back again, I land on my component but on TabIdx 3

Comment: I think you can achieve the desired result using the localstorage  and a event listener location.back() events.
My idea on how I would implement it, would be to store a state object in the localstorage, which would also contain a property, which decides if the state object should be used or not.
And on your location.back() event listener, you could decide to change the property to true, which means that it should use the previous state.

What do you think?

Comment: I think it could be a workaround - although I would do it with a service, not with localstorage. But I also think that actually there is a history-state-object for that and was hoping to get a more straight forward angular-solution rather than tricking myself around it.

Comment: Yeah I know.
But I really do not know another method.  You basically want to clear the state, when navigating to a new component. What about clearing some type of cache when navigating?